# Create a Custom Tab

Tags: ribbon, office-js

When I start a new Excel Web Add-in, by default the blank project has a `MyAppName.xml` file that declares the ribbon.
The declaration sets a custom group and a custom control under the native Home Excel tab.

What I want is to create a separate tab for my Addin.
In the file project itself, there are these code lines:

```
<!-- Use OfficeTab to extend an existing Tab. Use CustomTab to create a new tab. -->
<OfficeTab id="TabHome">
```

So I changed `OfficeTab` for `CustomTab`, but now I get the message in the error list:

```
The element 'CustomTab' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides' has incomplete content. List of possible elements expected: 'Group, Label' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides'.
```

Do you know how I can create a custom tab? What am I doing wrong?

I'm using:
Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 
Version 15.2 (26430.12) Release
VisualStudio.15.Release/15.2.0+26430.12

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is an example manifest that uses CustomTab. Can you compare your's with the example and see what might be different? Are you giving the CustomTab a unique ID? Does it have Group and Label child elements?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" xmlns:ov="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="TaskPaneApp">

<!-- See https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-Commands-Samples for documentation-->

<!-- BeginBasicSettings: Add-in metadata, used for all versions of Office unless override provided -->

<!--IMPORTANT! Id must be unique for your add-in. If you copy this manifest ensure that you change this id to your own GUID. -->
<Id>e504fb41-a92a-4526-b101-542f357b7acb</Id>
<Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
<ProviderName>Contoso</ProviderName>
<DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
<!-- The display name of your add-in. Used on the store and various placed of the Office UI such as the add-ins dialog -->
<DisplayName DefaultValue="Add-in Commands Sample" />
<Description DefaultValue="Sample that illustrates add-in commands basic control types and actions" />
<!--Icon for your add-in. Used on installation screens and the add-ins dialog -->
<IconUrl DefaultValue="https://contoso.com/assets/icon-32.png" />
<HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://contoso.com/assets/hi-res-icon.png" />
<SupportUrl DefaultValue="[Insert the URL of a page that provides support information for the app]" />
<!--BeginTaskpaneMode integration. Office 2013 and any client that doesn't understand commands will use this section.
  This section will also be used if there are no VersionOverrides -->
<Hosts>
  <Host Name="Document"/>
</Hosts>
<DefaultSettings>
  <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://commandsimple.azurewebsites.net/Taskpane.html" />
</DefaultSettings>
<!--EndTaskpaneMode integration -->

<Permissions>ReadWriteDocument</Permissions>

<!--BeginAddinCommandsMode integration-->
<VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
  <Hosts>
    <!--Each host can have a different set of commands. Cool huh!? -->
    <!-- Workbook=Excel Document=Word Presentation=PowerPoint -->
    <!-- Make sure the hosts you override match the hosts declared in the top section of the manifest -->
    <Host xsi:type="Document">
      <!-- Form factor. Currently only DesktopFormFactor is supported. We will add TabletFormFactor and PhoneFormFactor in the future-->
      <DesktopFormFactor>
        <!--Function file is an html page that includes the javascript where functions for ExecuteAction will be called.
        Think of the FunctionFile as the "code behind" ExecuteFunction-->
        <FunctionFile resid="Contoso.FunctionFile.Url" />

        <!--PrimaryCommandSurface==Main Office app ribbon-->
        <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="PrimaryCommandSurface">
          <!--Use OfficeTab to extend an existing Tab. Use CustomTab to create a new tab -->
          <!-- Documentation includes all the IDs currently tested to work -->
          <CustomTab id="Contoso.Tab1">
            <!--Group ID-->
            <Group id="Contoso.Tab1.Group1">
              <!--Label for your group. resid must point to a ShortString resource -->
              <Label resid="Contoso.Tab1.GroupLabel" />
              <Icon>
              <!-- Sample Todo: Each size needs its own icon resource or it will look distorted when resized -->
                <!--Icons. Required sizes: 16, 32, 80; optional: 20, 24, 40, 48, 64. You should provide as many sizes as possible for a great user experience. -->
                <!--Use PNG icons and remember that all URLs on the resources section must use HTTPS -->
                <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Icon16" />
                <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Icon32" />
                <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Icon80" />
              </Icon>

              <!--Control. It can be of type "Button" or "Menu" -->
              <Control xsi:type="Button" id="Contoso.FunctionButton">
                <!--Label for your button. resid must point to a ShortString resource -->
                <Label resid="Contoso.FunctionButton.Label" />
                <Supertip>
                  <!--ToolTip title. resid must point to a ShortString resource -->
                  <Title resid="Contoso.FunctionButton.Label" />
                  <!--ToolTip description. resid must point to a LongString resource -->
                  <Description resid="Contoso.FunctionButton.Tooltip" />
                </Supertip>
                <Icon>
                  <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.FunctionButton.Icon16" />
                  <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.FunctionButton.Icon32" />
                  <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.FunctionButton.Icon80" />
                </Icon>
                <!--This is what happens when the command is triggered (E.g. click on the Ribbon). Supported actions are ExecuteFunction or ShowTaskpane-->
                <!--Look at the FunctionFile.html page for reference on how to implement the function -->
                <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                  <!--Name of the function to call. This function needs to exist in the global DOM namespace of the function file-->
                  <FunctionName>writeText</FunctionName>
                </Action>
              </Control>

              <Control xsi:type="Button" id="Contoso.TaskpaneButton">
                <Label resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Label" />
                <Supertip>
                  <Title resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Label" />
                  <Description resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" />
                </Supertip>
                <Icon>
                  <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Icon16" />
                  <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Icon32" />
                  <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Icon80" />
                </Icon>
                <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                  <TaskpaneId>Button2Id1</TaskpaneId>
                  <!--Provide a url resource id for the location that will be displayed on the task pane -->
                  <SourceLocation resid="Contoso.Taskpane1.Url" />
                </Action>
              </Control>
              <!-- Menu example -->
              <Control xsi:type="Menu" id="Contoso.Menu">
                <Label resid="Contoso.Dropdown.Label" />
                <Supertip>
                  <Title resid="Contoso.Dropdown.Label" />
                  <Description resid="Contoso.Dropdown.Tooltip" />
                </Supertip>
                <Icon>
                  <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Icon16" />
                  <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Icon32" />
                  <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Icon80" />
                </Icon>
                <Items>
                  <Item id="Contoso.Menu.Item1">
                    <Label resid="Contoso.Item1.Label"/>
                    <Supertip>
                      <Title resid="Contoso.Item1.Label" />
                      <Description resid="Contoso.Item1.Tooltip" />
                    </Supertip>
                    <Icon>
                      <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Icon16" />
                      <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Icon32" />
                      <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Icon80" />
                    </Icon>
                    <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                      <TaskpaneId>MyTaskPaneID1</TaskpaneId>
                      <SourceLocation resid="Contoso.Taskpane1.Url" />
                    </Action>
                  </Item>

                  <Item id="Contoso.Menu.Item2">
                    <Label resid="Contoso.Item2.Label"/>
                    <Supertip>
                      <Title resid="Contoso.Item2.Label" />
                      <Description resid="Contoso.Item2.Tooltip" />
                    </Supertip>
                    <Icon>
                      <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Icon16" />
                      <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Icon32" />
                      <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Icon80" />
                    </Icon>
                    <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                      <TaskpaneId>MyTaskPaneID2</TaskpaneId>
                      <SourceLocation resid="Contoso.Taskpane2.Url" />
                    </Action>
                  </Item>

                </Items>
              </Control>

            </Group>

            <!-- Label of your tab -->
            <!-- If validating with XSD it needs to be at the end -->
            <Label resid="Contoso.Tab1.TabLabel" />
          </CustomTab>
        </ExtensionPoint>
      </DesktopFormFactor>
    </Host>
  </Hosts>
  <Resources>
    <bt:Images>
      <bt:Image id="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Icon16" DefaultValue="https://myCDN/Images/Button16x16.png" />
      <bt:Image id="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Icon32" DefaultValue="https://myCDN/Images/Button32x32.png" />
      <bt:Image id="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Icon80" DefaultValue="https://myCDN/Images/Button80x80.png" />
      <bt:Image id="Contoso.FunctionButton.Icon" DefaultValue="https://myCDN/Images/ButtonFunction.png" />
    </bt:Images>
    <bt:Urls>
      <bt:Url id="Contoso.FunctionFile.Url" DefaultValue="https://commandsimple.azurewebsites.net/FunctionFile.html" />
      <bt:Url id="Contoso.Taskpane1.Url" DefaultValue="https://commandsimple.azurewebsites.net/Taskpane.html" />
      <bt:Url id="Contoso.Taskpane2.Url" DefaultValue="https://commandsimple.azurewebsites.net/Taskpane2.html" />
    </bt:Urls>
    <bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:String id="Contoso.FunctionButton.Label" DefaultValue="Execute Function" />
      <bt:String id="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="Show Taskpane" />
      <bt:String id="Contoso.Dropdown.Label" DefaultValue="Dropdown" />
      <bt:String id="Contoso.Item1.Label" DefaultValue="Show Taskpane 1" />
      <bt:String id="Contoso.Item2.Label" DefaultValue="Show Taskpane 2" />
      <bt:String id="Contoso.Tab1.GroupLabel" DefaultValue="Test Group" />
       <bt:String id="Contoso.Tab1.TabLabel" DefaultValue="Test Tab" />
    </bt:ShortStrings>
    <bt:LongStrings>
      <bt:String id="Contoso.FunctionButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Click to Execute Function" />
      <bt:String id="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Click to Show a Taskpane" />
      <bt:String id="Contoso.Dropdown.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Click to Show Options on this Menu" />
      <bt:String id="Contoso.Item1.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Click to Show Taskpane1" />
      <bt:String id="Contoso.Item2.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Click to Show Taskpane2" />
    </bt:LongStrings>
  </Resources>
</VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

See also this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/add-in-commands-for-outlook) and the samples it links to. And check out [Validate and Troubleshoot your Manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/troubleshoot-manifest) too.

Comment: I got it working by the example in the link, thanks.
The issue is that when you change `OfficeTab` for `CustomTab`, you must also create a `<Label resid="Tab.Label">` element.

Comment: I found that the `<Label>` needs to go after the `<Group>`. I also found that I had to rebuild the solution to make the error go away.